# Problems in Adding File Types to 'New' Context Menu in File Explorer using regedit

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu, regedit

#### Issue with Adding File Types to 'New' Context Menu in File Explorer

I'm encountering difficulties adding certain file types to the 'New' option in the right-click context menu in File Explorer. If relevant, I'm using *Windows 11 Home*, but I did **[the registry trick to get the old *Windows 10* context menu back](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restore-old-right-click-context-menu-in-windows-11/a62e797c-eaf3-411b-aeec-e460e6e5a82a)**. My approach involved navigating to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.whateverfileextension`, creating a new key named 'ShellNew', and adding a String value to it named 'NullFile' with a value of 1.

However, when attempting the same for `.py` files at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py`, it didn't work. Upon further investigation, I found that `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` does not have a 'PersistentHandler' key, unlike most other file extensions. Adding a 'PersistentHandler' key isn't as easy as it sounds though, as each one requires a String value with its own unique UUID (at least according to what I currently know).

Through some more testing, it appears that for a file type to be added to the 'New' option in the File Explorer context menu, it needs to have an 'OpenWithProgids' key, a 'PersistentHandler' key, and a 'ShellNew' key. One exception is the `.bmp` file, which is added to the context menu using a value in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MrtCache\C:%5CProgram Files%5CWindowsApps%5CMicrosoft.Paint_11.2311.29.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe%5Cmicrosoft.system.package.metadata%5CS-1-5-21-1802110441-852385161-1113275907-1001-MergedResources-6.pri\1da45b55b7b39b7\dbf1b25e`. Only some of the file extensions meet these requirements, mainly the more common ones like `.txt` or `.exe`, or even less common but still common ones like `.html` or `.js`.

#### Main Question

Does anyone know how I can still add the file type to the 'New' option despite the missing requirement, or is there a way to make the file extension meet these criteria?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The tutorial you linked is just a bunch of .reg scripts to add or remove items that are already there by default. And the ShellMenuNew program that you linked also only shows the ones there by default.